# Small images next to a h1 title

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple problem but am unable to wrap my head around it. At least for an elegant solution.

I want to display an image to the right of a title which should be centered on the page.

```
<h1>My title</h1><img src="smallicon.png"/>
```

So "My title" should be in the middle of the page and the icon to the right of it.
If I set float: left on the header then it has the icon to its right but of course now is no longer centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a really simple way is using flexbox (when you have a container with the class "header" around the title):

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I can use it for me since that is not a requirement

Answer (score 0):

Move the icon to either be inside of or before the header, then set it (the image) to `float:right`.

Comment: This does not work, now the image is on the far right border and not next to the title

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>My title <img src="smallicon.png" /></h1>
```

This? Or do you want the text to be centered, but not the image?

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
}
h1 img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
```